# Однородные / неоднородные определения

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно расставить запятые в предложении: Выпеченный полуфабрикат в виде лепешек из дрожжевого теста обычно с различными начинками. 
Являются ли "в виде лепешек", "из дрожжевого теста", "обычно с различными начинками" однородными определениями, относящимися к слову "полуфабрикат"?

Comment: Лучше, по-моему, немного поменять порядок слов:

_**Выпеченный в виде лепешек полуфабрикат  из дрожжевого теста, обычно с различными начинками.**_   Или там не такой смысл?

Comment: Спасибо. Но это из специальной литературы, там принят такой порядок (например, не пшеничная мука, а мука пшеничная). А смысл такой, только нужно сохранить порядок слов.

Answer (score 3):

Выпеченный полуфабрикат в виде лепешек из дрожжевого теста, обычно с различными начинками.

Существительное "полуфабрикат" имеет два основных определения (согласованное "выпеченный" и несогласованное "в виде лепешек из дрожжевого теста" и обособленное уточняющее определение "обычно с различными начинками".

Comment: Спасибо большое! Интересует, не нужно ли ставить запятую перед "из дрожжевого теста". Полуфабрикат (какой?)  в виде лепешек, полуфабрикат (какой?) из дрожжевого теста.

Comment: Думаю. что не надо, не стоит разделять запятой "выпеченный из дрожжевого теста", между ними тесная смысловая связь.